# Array: 4th dimension, isset return not reliable

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Does anybody know, how it can be, that this code echoes `yahoo`? There is clearly no 4th array with the key 'something', but it keeps thinking it's like that. Bug? Feature?

```
$array = array('a' => array('b' => array('c' => 'test')));
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($array);
echo '</pre>';
if (isset($array['a']['b']['c']['something'])) {
    echo 'yahoo';
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because PHP thinks you are checking the 'something'th place of the string 'test'. Remember, strings are arrays of characters. try to echo $array['a']['b']['c']['something'].

::EDIT::

I Explained it, I didn't say it made sense. :P

Comment: So the correct way would be to do an is_array-check on something?

Comment: is_array() would work fine. ::edit:: Yes, I realize that makes even less sense...

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I think in my case a check with array_key_exists() should do the trick!

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to use `is_array($array['a']['b']['c'])` rather than `isset($array['a']['b']['c']['something'])` in this case, or maybe a crafty combination of the two to make sure you don't get any errors if it's not set when you're checking to see if it's an array.

Something like:

```
if(isset($array['a']['b']['c']['something']) && is_array($array['a']['b']['c'])){ [...] }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.zomeoff.com/php-isset-and-multi-dimentional-array/)  has discussed the behavior of PHP in this issue and provides a solution that is exactly for your problem.